# Remap Win+arrow shortcuts in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a keyboard without multimedia functions, and I'd like to have volume up/down and playback control shortcuts. Since I'm not using `Windows Key` + `Arrow` shortcuts, I'd like to map them to those functions.

How can I do that?

Comment: As far as I've found out, it isn't possible to bind Windows key shortcuts with AutoIT on Windows 10... Maybe there's another way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following example script will map
<kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> to <kbd>Volume Up</kbd>
and
<kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> to <kbd>Volume Down</kbd>:

```
#Right:: Volume_Up
#Left:: Volume_Down
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and double-click
it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: Whoa, it works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer to use windows applications you can use [Windows Power Toys](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys)

In the Keyboard Manager tool (submenu), you can select the shortcuts you're talking about and map it to anything you like including <kbd>Win</kbd>+ <kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>Down</kbd>, <kbd>Left</kbd>, or <kbd>Right</kbd> arrows.